# iphone:UIToolbar when set to tint color behaves differently on iOS 5 and ios6 simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

If I set the color of toolbar as tint color and run the application on ios5 simulator. It shows the color well. But when I run the same application on ios6 simulator, it show the toolbar color blurred?

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: how do you set the color with settTintColor?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832851/iphone-why-the-toolbar-color-is-showing-blurred-effect-in-ios6-and-not-in-ios5

Comment: toolbaroutlet.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:.30 green:.40 blue:.80 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 0):

i use the following code to change tint coor and background image of all toolbars and it workds perfect

```
UIToolbar *dummyToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
if ([dummyToolbar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:)]) {
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:kNAvigationColorTitleColor];
    UIImage *aImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackGround.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:6];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:aImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: have you tried to run the code on ios6 simulator and ios5 simulator? i can still see the change in the color effect.

Comment: you just try to change the color of toolbar using toolbar outlet.tintcolor in the viewdidload section.

Comment: actually due to some external libraries that is not avalaible for simulator we only test the app on real devces and it seems to be ok in both ios 5 and 6