# UIToolbar shows different color on ios 5.0 and ios 6.0 Simulators

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I have set tintcolor for my UIToolBar.It displays Correctly in ios 6.0 but it shows black color on ios 5.0 simulator. My code is here

```
originalBounds = mysearchBarBarItem.customView.bounds;
mySearchBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,215,44);
myTopToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND]];
myTopToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

mySearchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
mySearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND]];

[myTopToolbar setItems:toolBarItemsArray animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did you check this in device?

Comment: I have checked this in real iOS 6.0 hardware.It Displays correctly. I dont have iOS 5.0 real device to test.I have tested it iOS 5.0 simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this can make a difference, but you could try to change the order in which you assign the style and color of the bar. Try:

```
myTopToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;   
myTopToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND]];
```

It's possible that assigning the style after changing the tintcolor resets the color.

**EDIT**

Why this would affect only ios5 and not ios6 I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UIAppearance` (for iOS 5.0 and above) .

Answer (score 1):

Try to set color property

```
myTopToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If this works fine in both iOS6 and iOS5, then problem should be in image.

**Edited**
Check this question

[iphone:UIToolbar when set to tint color behaves differently on iOS 5 and ios6 simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833628/iphoneuitoolbar-when-set-to-tint-color-behaves-differently-on-ios-5-and-ios6-si)

Comment: You can check this in iOS5 device. i hope you wont get any problem in device

Comment: Did you check this in device

Comment: Dont have ios 5.0 device to check it.

Comment: i think it wont create any problem in device.

Comment: By the way I'm using same Image on my Navigation bar.It displays Correctly on both.So I dont think there is problem with Image.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this in your app delegate implementation class this will change the toolBar and searchBar color throughout the application

for setting tint of searchbar

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND]]];
```

OR

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:102/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

for setting tint of toolbar

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND]];
```

OR

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:102/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

for setting background image

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgtoolbar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: That's strange please try this [[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:102/255.0 alpha:1]]; and [[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:102/255.0 alpha:1]];

Comment: That worked. Got a very light Black color. But It has changed the color of toolbars in entire application.

Comment: yes that will change tollbar color throughout the application if you use it in app delegate, if you want specific toolbar in any viewController to change then do it in your that viewController

Answer (score 0):

I have solveed It. just converted the Image to RGB Values and set like this.

```
myTopToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:139/256.0 green:0/256.0 blue:0/256.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: You should be dividing by 255.0