# Set UIToolbar tint color captured from an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, colors

Our designer created some picture and the application has a UIToolbar at the top of the screen. I captured the RGB values of the bar's color, but when I set the tint color in the code based on these values I got different color than on the picture can be seen.
How can I set exactly the same tint color that I can see on the picture?

Thanks,
madik

Comment: Please find the below question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098743/uitoolbar-shows-different-color-on-ios-5-0-and-ios-6-0-simulators

Comment: First it is about using image, second UIAppearance can be use only from iOS5 and I have to support iOS4 too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTintcolor:` to set the color

To get pattern color from image
use  `colorWithPatternImage:`

```
[toolbar setTintColor:  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Myimagename"]];
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use an image? I have RGB values, so is there any calculation for get the same color as a tint color?

Comment: see `setTintColor:` accepts UIColor object you can set an uicolor object there with rgb values

Comment: I know it can, not this was the question. But if I use the same rgb values for tint color that I caputred from the image I got different color for toolbar that can be seen on the picture.